# How to make my android app connectable to BLE headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm working on android application that acts like BLE Peripheral (using Nexus 9 which is able to work like BLE Peripheral) so it provides some services and characteristics. I'm able to interact with it and it's ok.

How can i make it connectable to BLE headset now?
I can see HEADSET BLE profile enum value:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#HEADSET

Does it mean i need to implement some specific service, characteristics and some specific logics to support transferring sound to BLE headset?

Let's say i'd like to record real-time audio and transfer in to BLE headset. How can i stream sound real-time data to BLE headset?

Comment: Hello, did you ever get an answer? I'd like to send and receive audio to/from a headset, preferably over BLE.